# Вырезать разделитель и миллисекунды в строке Date с помощью replace

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z`, полученная из объекта Date. Из нее нужно вырезать разделитель **Т**, а также миллисекунды с **Z**, то есть последние 5 символов, включая точку. Какое регулярное выражение подходит здесь для `replace` в javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let rExp = /T|.{5}$/g;
let sTxt = '2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z';

console.log( sTxt.replace(rExp, ' ').trim() );
```

Без `trim()`:

```js
let rExp = /([\d-]+)T([\d:]+).{5}$/g;
let sTxt = '2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z';

console.log( sTxt.replace(rExp, '$1 $2') );
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const date = '2017-04-20T10:30:00.000Z';

// Вырезать T можно дедовским способом
console.log(date.split('T').join(' '));

// Последние 5 символов можно обрезать так
console.log( date.substr( 0, date.length - 5 ) );
// или чуть короче
console.log( date.slice( 0, -5 ) )
```